# Android Studio won't grab svg image

Tags: android-studio

When I go right click on Drawable->new->vector asset->local file and then select and image, it will not load it in and keeps saying 'Please select a file". I have tried different formats to the image and sizes, but nothing will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddy, after that you have to choose the path of the image also, their will an text file asking -"PATH" , click on the folder botton on that text column and choose the file you want to get.